# How is a varactor diode used in a circuit when it only has 2 terminals?

Tags: capacitor

I've been reading about varicaps, and I'd like to try to use one in an op-amp integrator circuit to be able to adjust the gain.

[image]

My confusion though is that every varactor diode datasheet I've read indicates that only 2 pins are used, like a normal diode.  The capacitance is supposed to change with reverse voltage across the diode, but how then is the capacitor supposed to be used in useful way?

[image]

**Only 2 pins used in both package types!**

Doesn't make any sense to me, since obviously you can't keep the diode at a constant reverse voltage AND use it in any type of circuit where an alternating waveform is applied. I was expecting them to have a 3rd pin where an external control voltage was applied.

What am I missing?

Comment: Just to clarify: at what frequency are you concerned about this gain control? Normally you'd have a negative feedback resistor for gain control at low frequencies.

Comment: My idea was to select Ri so that maximum gain desired occurs at low frequency (200Hz), and be able to lower Cf as frequency increases (20-100kHz)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> you can't keep the diode at a constant reverse voltage AND use it in
>   any type of circuit where an alternating waveform is applied.

Sure you can as the millions of [varactor tuners](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electronic/varactor.html) produced will testify.

[image]

Of course, the AC signal must be relatively *small*.  From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varicap#Tuning_circuits).

> When designing tuning circuits with varicaps it is usually good
>   practice to maintain the AC component of voltage across the varicap at
>   a minimal level, usually less than 100mV peak to peak, to prevent this
>   changing the capacitance of the diode too much and thus distorting the
>   signal and adding harmonics to it.

Comment: So the simulator I'm using doesn't have varactors.  Would this essentially be modeled exactly the way that schematic looks, with 2 inward facing diodes into a capacitor?

Comment: @krb686, the symbol is suggestive but not a model.  Take a look at this for ideas:  http://www.skyworksinc.com/uploads/documents/200315b.pdf‎

Comment: Thanks that looks very helpful.  Wow, 5 components to model a varactor.

Answer (score 3):

A typical application of a varicap diode is in a simple FM modulator. In a colpitts oscillator it can form part of the LC tuned circuit and in this type of configuration it usually is wired in series with another capacitor and one end grounded. This means a dc control voltage can be applied (through a high value resistor). The resistor is to ensure the dc control voltage does not upset the operation of the tuned circuit.

This is a common example. In your circuit, you have a varicap from output to the inverting input of your op-amp (presumably in an attempt to control gain at high frequencies or maybe it's acting as a variable integrator). To be able to control the dc voltage on the varicap I'd connect it in series with another capacitor and use a high value resistor to the junction of varicap and added capacitor. The added capacitor I'd put directly onto the output with the varicap on the inverting input. This means one side of the varicap remains largely at 0V (due to virtual earth config of op-amp). This makes controlling the varicap a bit more linear. You can also use back-to-back varicaps.

Comment: You got it.  Yes, I want to be able to have gain compensation for higher frequencies, allowing for a relatively constant output level.  I tried your suggestion, but I guess I'm still a little confused.  The simulator I'm using doesn't have varactors, so I've just put a diode in series with a capacitor.  Is this what you suggested? - http://bit.ly/19l0Mxr

Looks like it doesn't work

Comment: Could you post the circuit to your question area. My browser is being stupid and not showing it. Let me know when done but it's late here in the uk so it'll be tomorrow. Post a reminder comment in case I forget please.

Comment: Here it is:

http://i306.photobucket.com/albums/nn255/Krb686/varicap_simple_model.png